# Retrieve data tables from database with stored procedure

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

Let me explain you in details the scenario that I am having and the solution I am looking for.
Firstfully, I created a stored procedure that outputs simple things such as 2 tables and a message 'don't stop here'"

**T-SQL:**

```
USE [mydb]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[BackupDatabase]    Script Date: 2/26/2013 11:29:10 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[testing]
AS
BEGIN
    select 'A' firstname, 'B' lastname;

    print 'dont stop here'

    select 1 final
END
```

Up until now I used to retriew the tables in a single manner by using datarowcollection class, and my static method looked like this:

**C#:**

```
 public static class DataMan
    {
        public static DataRowCollection SelectData(string sql)
        {
            SqlDataSource DS = new SqlDataSource(CS, sql);
            return ((DataView)DS.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty)).ToTable().Rows;
        }
public static string CS =  ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
}
```

where I can easily get what i needed like here, and locate what evver row I wanted:

```
DataRowCollection people = Util.SelectData("Select * from students")
```

But now I am planning to create a stored procedure Like I mentioned above and do somthing like this, for instance:

```
**DataTableCollection** people = Util.SelectData("exec dbo.Testing")
```

**UPDATE:**

so I can locate the specific table from my storedprocedure.

I have tried to use DataTable, DataSet, DataTableCollections but no success.I can't use them in proper way.

Please help me

Thank You

Comment: is that really possible, or I am just dangling. By the way the "Utils" out there are actually "DataMan" class.

Comment: This is why we use ado.net's sql command object kids.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although it can be used in code-behind as you're illustrating here, the SqlDataSource is more typically used in a declarative manner on an ASP.NET markup page. However, given what you've started, when calling a stored procedure, you should set the `SqlCommandType` to `StoredProcedure`, supply the name of the procedure to `SelectCommand`, and return a `DataReader`. The `DataReader`, in turn, supports a `NextResult()` method that you can call to retrieve each discrete result set your procedure provides. Here is a framework of pseudo code that tries to illustrate how you might leverage this:

```
// pseudo code
void stub()
{
   SqlDataSource d = new SqlDataSource(*connection string*);
   d.DataSourceMode = SqlDataSourceMode.DataReader;
   d.SelectCommandType = SqlDataSourceCommandType.StoredProcedure;
   d.SelectCommand = "dbo.Testing";
   // set some parameters 
   d.SelectParameters.Add("Parameter1Name","Parameter1Value"); // must be tailored to your proc!!
   d.SelectParameters.Add("Parameter2Name","Parameter2Value"); // must be tailored to        SqlDataReader r = (SqlDataReader) d.Select();

   while (r.HasRows)
   {
       while (r.Read())
       {
           // do something with each row
       }
       // advance to next result set
       r.NextResult();
   }

   r.Close();
}
```

Comment: By setting it to `StoredProcedure` don't you exclude the `exec` part of the `SelectCommand`?  Otherwise it's redundant?  That's how a `SqlCommand` works anyway -- without the explicit `exec`.

Comment: That's what I get for *typing* and not *reading*. Good catch! Fixed.

Comment: Thank you, I tried this and looks like it's gonna work, the only problem is SqlDataReader r doesn't except the d.Select()  type.

Comment: I neglected to put in the cast from the Select command to the SqlDataReader. That should fix it. Select returns an IDataReader, which must be explicitly cast to a concrete implementation, eg SqlDataReader.

Comment: Thanks @INgeeg :). Glad to help; that's what we're here for. I amended the example to show how you can try adding parameters - mind you, they obviously have to match up with your actual procedure's parameter(s), but the idea is there :)

Comment: @Ingeeg You're not stupid. You're willing to learn. Just keep after it and help someone else someday! I've been doing stuff like this for 25+ years...